# Programming with Fortran, large eigen value problem

Tags: fortran

I use matlab/fortran to deal with some large eigenvalue problem (FEM type).

For example, I use spalloc and eigs to declare and solve the problem in Matlab,

could anyone give some advice on how can I do it in Fortran? any routine like spalloc/eigs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your matrices are dense, then [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) is the way to go.  If they are sparse, then [ARPACK](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/arpack-ng/) is often better suited.

There is no standard equivalent of spalloc: LAPACK only supports dense matrices and ARPACK lets you store the data however you like, you just compute the action $A x$ for it.

You may also want to check out this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293282/can-i-use-lapack-for-calculating-the-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-large-spars).

Comment: what did you mean by "store the data however you like". the problem is essentially two steps, 1) how to declare A as a sparse matrix, 2) how to solve Ax=lBy?

Comment: With ARPACK, you don't actually pass a matrix to the library.  Instead, it uses a "reverse communication interface" to give you a vector, x, and ask you to compute y = Ax for it.  In a sense, your 'matrix' is really a linear operator that you can implement however you like.  Ref: http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node9.html

Comment: however, in order to save memory, I want to use banded storage, do you know any routine that is able to format a sparse matrix A in banded form?

Comment: I don't know of any.  You should probably just explicitly populate it.  If the matrix is banded and symmetric (or Hermitian), then you can use BLAS (http://www.netlib.org/blas/dsbmv.f of zhbmv.f) and LAPACK (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/complex16/dsbev.f or zhbev.f).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need (distributed memory) parallelization, LAPACK or ARPACK depending on the sparsity of your problems are good choices, as already answered by Max Hutchinson.

Large parallel eigenvalue solvers are a topic for ongoing research. For sparse problems, check out e.g. [SLEPc](http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/), for dense problems [ELPA](http://elpa.rzg.mpg.de/) could be interesting for you if the old workhorse [ScaLAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/) doesn't cut it. The [ELPA wiki](http://elpa-lib.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) contains links to a few other parallel eigensolvers as well.